# How do I integrate the invite multiple friends from facebook to my site

Tags: facebook

I want to integrate an invite friends from facebook option like how foursquare have implemented it. I checked out the [fb:Request form](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/) but wasn't able to run it successfully. Plus I heard theyre deprecating the legacy FBML  library so is there any better way of doing this?

I'm working  in php here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Facebook [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) has replaced it.  It uses the Facebook javascript SDK.

**Full example** ([click here](http://jsfiddle.net/offbysome/vyN6V/) to run it on jsfiddle):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="sendRequests();return false;">Invite your friends</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: '**yourAppId**', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml : true });

  function sendRequests() {  
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'You should learn more about this awesome site.', data: 'tracking information for the user'}, 
    function(response) {
        if (response != null && response.request_ids && response.request_ids.length >0) {
          for(var i = 0; i < response.request_ids.length; i++) {
            alert("Invited: " + response.request_ids[i]);
          }
        } else {
          alert('No invitations sent');
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```